# обратный слеш в json_decode из js в php

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
// js 
....
let str = [{"id":1,"name":"1","time_working":"8"},{"id":2,"name":"1","time_working":"9"},{"id":3,"name":"1","time_working":"10"},{"id":4,"name":"1","time_working":"11"},{"id":5,"name":"1","time_working":"12"},{"id":6,"name":"1","time_working":"13"},{"id":7,"name":"1","time_working":"14"},{"id":8,"name":"1","time_working":"15"},{"id":9,"name":"1","time_working":"16"},{"id":10,"name":"1","time_working":"17"},{"id":11,"name":"1","time_working":"18"},{"id":12,"name":"1","time_working":"19"}];
str = JSON.stringify(str);

// далее отправляем строку в php XMLHttpRequest
```

....

```
//php
// получаю данные всё ок

 $str_res_trlights =  $_POST['name_data'];

//  вывожу полученную строку отоборажается со слешами

echo $str_res_trlights; 
/* 
[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"8\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"9\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"10\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"11\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"12\"},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"13\"},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"14\"},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"15\"},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"16\"},{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"17\"},{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"18\"},{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"1\",\"time_working\":\"19\"}]
*/
// далее пытаюсь декодировать json_decode

$arr_res = json_decode($str_res_trlights); 
var_dump( $arr_res); 

// получаю null
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас строка уже изначально в JSON. Вы ее повторно пихаете в JSON. Оттуда и null.

Front

```
let str = '[{"id":1,"name":"1","time_working":"8"},{"id":2,"name":"1","time_working":"9"},{"id":3,"name":"1","time_working":"10"},{"id":4,"name":"1","time_working":"11"},{"id":5,"name":"1","time_working":"12"},{"id":6,"name":"1","time_working":"13"},{"id":7,"name":"1","time_working":"14"},{"id":8,"name":"1","time_working":"15"},{"id":9,"name":"1","time_working":"16"},{"id":10,"name":"1","time_working":"17"},{"id":11,"name":"1","time_working":"18"},{"id":12,"name":"1","time_working":"19"}]';
```

Back

```
// получили данные
$str_res_trlights =  $_POST['name_data'];
$arr_res = json_decode($str_res_trlights,true); 
print_r($arr_res);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => 1
            [time_working] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => 1
            [time_working] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => 1
            [time_working] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => 1
            [time_working] => 11
    .....
```

Comment: Когда разместил здесь код оптимизировал его. И не правильно указал let str = '[ там конечно let str = [  без '' . Проверил типы переменных всё верно но всё= не работает

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему убрав слеши

```
$arr_res = json_decode( stripcslashes($str_res_trlights), true);
var_dump( $arr_res);
```